What is the probability that the distance of any three points in a cube (side length: $1$) is less than $1/3$?
The probability that the distance of any there points in a cube of side length $1$ is less than $1/3$ is equivalent to find the volume of the following region:
\begin{align}
|x_1 - x_2| &\leq 1/3 \\
|x_2 - x_3| &\leq 1/3 \\
|x_3 - x_1| &\leq 1/3, \\
\end{align}
with $0 \leq x_1, x_2, x_3 \leq 1.$
How can I find volume of this region?

Your title says "less than 1/3" while your text says "=<1".  Which is it and what have you tried?

oh i am sorry, i took a mistake. What i want to mean was 1/3.

What have you tried?

I tried to find volume of that region due to geometric probability. So I used inclusion-exclusion principle. But i failed.

A first step would be to distinguish $x_1\in (0,1/3)$, $x_1\in (1/3,2/3)$ and $x_1\in (2/3,1)$. Try this if you want.

We are in a cube, in 3-dimension. So I suppose that our points are $M_1(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ ,  $M_1(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ and $M_1(x_3,y_3,z_3)$. If so, this exercise is really complex. If we are in 1-dimension, as the 1st comments suggest, it is more simple. Maybe the 1st step is to work in dim.1, to correctly understand the challenge, what are the equations   for such a question.

I doubt this is easy.  Quick and dirty simulation suggests something near  $0.0063$ for the probability for all three to be within $\frac13$ of the others, which seems surprisingly small.
